# Why does attoparsec use 100 times more memory than my input file?

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

I have a 2.5 MB file full of floats separated by spaces (the code below can generate it for you) and want to parse it into an array with `attoparsec`.

It is surprisingly slow, taking almost a second, and allocating a lot of memory:

```
time ./Attoparsec-problem +RTS -sstderr < floats.txt
299999.0
   956,647,344 bytes allocated in the heap
   752,875,520 bytes copied during GC
   166,485,416 bytes maximum residency (7 sample(s))
     8,874,168 bytes maximum slop
           337 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                  Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
Gen  0      1604 colls,     0 par    0.21s    0.27s     0.0002s    0.0092s
Gen  1         7 colls,     0 par    0.24s    0.36s     0.0520s    0.1783s

...

%GC     time      65.5%  (75.1% elapsed)

Alloc rate    3,985,781,488 bytes per MUT second

Productivity  34.5% of total user, 28.6% of total elapsed
```

My parser is incredibly simple: It is essentially `double <* skipSpace`.

This is the code:

```hs
import           Control.Applicative
import           Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8 as A
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U

-- Compile with:
-- ghc --make -O2 -prof -auto-all -caf-all -rtsopts -fforce-recomp Attoparsec-problem.hs

-- Run:
-- time ./Attoparsec-problem +RTS -sstderr < floats.txt

main :: IO ()
main = do

  -- For creating the test file (2.5 MB)
  -- writeFile "floats.txt" (Prelude.unwords $ Prelude.map show [1.0,2.0..300000.0])

  r <- parse parser <$> BS.getContents
  case r of
    Done _ arr -> print $ U.last arr
    x          -> print x

  where
    parser = do
      U.replicateM (300000-1) (double <* skipSpace)


-- This gives surprisingly bad productivity (70% GC time) and 180 MB max residency
-- for a 2.5 MB file!
```

Can you explain me what is going on?

Comment: I suspect that replicateM is interacting badly with parsec's backtracking. For me, using the parser `many' (double <* skipSpace)` and fromList to generate the vector runs roughly twice as fast (and with 58% productivity) despite the extra list allocation.

Comment: @Zeta I cannot reproduce what you say. How did you get that number? I still have 120 MB residency with `attoparsec-0.12.1.1` and GGHC 7.6.3. With GHC 7.8, it even gets much worse: 420 MB, amd 55% productivity. I'm compiling with `ghc --make -O2 -rtsopts -fforce-recomp Attoparsec-problem.hs`.